# Nancy.DynamicDictionary does not contain a definition for X

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nancy

When  running in the VS2015 debugger, just today, never before, in my Routing call, the debugger claims that "Nancy.DynamicDictionary does not contain a definition for v.company_id", which is the variable that I defined in the route as such:

```
Get["/companies/{company_id}/connection/validate"] = v => Validate( v.company_id );
```

But when I run from the console all is fine.  Running 3 days ago from VS2015 all was fine.  Why on earth is this dynamic being treated differently today?  This has been working for months now.

UPDATE:  I am using VS2015 Community on the machine where this happens.  On other machines with standard VS2015 editions, this works flawlessly.

Answer (score 4):

I've noticed this strange, inconsistent behavior before as well. I believe the error goes away if you replace `v.company_id` with `v["company_id"]`.

Comment: I would very much appreciate if you'd accept my answer, since it does solve the problem without requiring a re-installation.

Answer (score 0):

I re installed visual studio and the issue went away. Not the most satisfying answer, though.